# Javascript :: Loop background color that the last color would always be on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, background

My code is working with 2 issues.

1. I have to use the !important to trigger the first loop.
2. It's not looping back to the first color.

I want to remove the !important and make it loop completely.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no z-index for background color?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>&nbsp;</title>
<style>

:root
{
    --color0:#000;
    --color1:green;
    --color2:yellow;
    --color3:red
}

body
{
    background-color:#eee
}

div
{
    background-color:transparent;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:30px;
    width:300px
}

div:nth-child(2)
{
    background-color:var(--color0)
}

.green
{
    background-color:var(--color1) !important
}

.yellow
{
    background-color:var(--color2) !important
}

.red
{
    background-color:var(--color3) !important
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>David Gilmour</div>
<div>Hezi Gangina</div>
<div>Steve Vai</div>

<script>

var looper=0;
var divs=document.querySelectorAll("div");

setInterval(function()
{
    switch(looper)
    {
        case 0:
            divs[1].classList.add("green");
            break;
        case 1:
            divs[1].classList.add("yellow");
            break;
        case 2:
            divs[1].classList.add("red");
            break;
    }
    looper++;
    if(looper===3){looper=0}
},1000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, my goal is to get rid of all !important and make it loop forever. I have tried z-index property, but without any luck...

I guess the cleanest solution is to set the last color always as the top layer, and it would solve all problems, but z-index is not an option here...

Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's first map the class names according to the counter (looper) value:

```
var classes = {
    1: 'green',
    2: 'yellow',
    3: 'red',
};
// set your counter outside the interval
var counter = 1;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    // remove previous class values of the div, so that no overriding will take place
    divs[1].classList.value = '';
    // add the class name according to counter value
    divs[1].classList.add(classes[counter]);

    // either reset or increment your counter
    counter = counter >= 3 ? 1 : counter + 1;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the class. `divs[1].classList.remove("color");`. In every case.

Comment: But in that method I still have to use the !important :D